# Cordova iOS application directory and file url differs (UUID issue)

Tags: ios, cordova, ember.js, path, uuid

I've created a Cordova application that fetches images from a server and saves them to an iPad. However, when trying to display the images in the application, the images will not load. One example of such a file path could be:

```
file:///var/mobile/Containers/data/Application/FC87E925-9753-4D9F-AE27-54FCF9B0451E/Documents/-media-3405-company.png
```

However, when inspecting the `cordova.file.applicationDirectory` variable, I find another path, e.g. (note that the UUID differ even though I'm inspecting both variables in the same run)

```
file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/D8266D08-18A4-4293-B78A-B4597FC0C6B8/salesApp.app/
```

Accordingly to the [documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/#ios-file-system-layout), the correct path "should" be: (however, that does not work either)

```
file:///var/mobile/Applications/UUID/Documents/-media-3405-company.png
```

Here is the code I use to load the images, which are correctly saved to the device

```
const downloadFile = (url, fileName, callback) => {
      window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, (fs) => {
          fs.root.getFile(fileName, {
            create: true,
            exclusive: false
          }, (fileEntry) => {
            const fileURL = fileEntry.toURL()
            const fileTransfer = new FileTransfer()
            fileTransfer.download(
              url,
              fileURL,
              (entry) => {
                const file = entry.toURL() // <--- HERE
                content.pushObject('Downloaded ' + entry + ' (' + fileName + ') ' + file)
                callback(file)
              },
              (error) => {
                content.pushObject('error ' + error.code + '(' + fileName + ')')
                if (error.code === FileTransferError.CONNECTION_ERR) {
                  downloadFile(url, fileName) // Try again
                } else {
                  decrement(url) // Ignore this file
                }
              }
            )
          }, (error) => {
            alert(2)
          })
      }, () => {
        alert(3)
      })
    }
```

Update: Inspecting the value for `cordova.file.documentsDirectory`, I found that it returns a path similar to: `file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/{UUID}/Documents/`.

Update: The following code will return two different UUIDs:

```
alert(cordova.file.applicationDirectory); // file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/54E0F914-C45B-4B8F-9067-C13AF1967760/salesApp.app/
alert(cordova.file.documentsDirectory);   // file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/73806E90-90B4-488C-A68A-2715C3627489/Documents/
```

When inspecting the path for `entry.toURL()` i get the same UUIDs as the one returned in `cordova.file.documentsDirectory`.

Comment: @Martin I guess you gotta use entry.nativeURL Check out this working sample which should help - https://github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_File_Operations

Comment: I guess you gotta use entry.nativeURL Check out this working sample which should help - github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_File_Operations

Comment: also in the link you mentioned - https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/#ios-file-system-layout its clearly indicated that 'applicationStorageDirectory' is read only. you cant write to it

Comment: Using either `entry.NativeURL` or `entry.toNativeURL()` i get the following path: `file:///var/mobile/Containers/Application/{UUID}/Documents/{filename}`, which is identical to the one from `entry.toURL()`.

Comment: Accordingly to the [documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/#ios-persistent-storage-location) the documents directory is the default location for saving files, which is read/write. I can also confirm, by inspecting the Container for the application (through Xcode), that the images are, in fact, saved to the correct directory on the device. However, the files are still not visible in the UI (the path is still wrong I believe)

Comment: did you tried out the working sample i referred to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you claim that "images will not load", then you should provide the code used to load the images.
The code you provided is to download the images and it works fine.

As you didn't provide the code used to load the images I have tried two things and both of them worked

1. Open the file on InAppBrowser. I installed the cordova-plugin-inappbrowser and opened the file like this `window.open(file,'_blank');`
2. Display the file on a img tag. I created a img tag in my index.html `<img id="downloaded" src=""/>` and on my callback I assign the file obtained to the src `document.getElementById("downloaded").src = file;`

Both of them worked.

So you should provide your code used to load the images because the problem might be there.

The path you are getting on the download is ok.

You are getting different UUIDs because the docs are outdated. Before Xcode 6/iOS8 the app sandbox had the Bundle container and the Data container inside the same folder (the one the docs mention with a common UUID), but since Xcode 6/iOS8 the app files (Bundle container) are in a path and the App data files are in another one (Data container).

But that shouldn't be a problem for you.

[Answer that talks about the file structure changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27263333/how-can-i-access-specific-ios-apps-directory-with-objective-c)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did not include any code regarding the loading of the images since it's a bit more complex. Basically, I store the url (string) from `fileEntry.toURL()` and display it in an image tag, e.g. `<img src="file:///var/mobile/Containers/data/Application/FC87E925-9753-4D9F-AE27-54FCF9B0451E/Documents/-media-3405-company.png" alt="" />` using Ember.

Comment: I'm using this code as explained on point 2 `downloadFile('http://k33.kn3.net/taringa/0/3/5/1/2/9/marceloceirano99/21E.png','-‌​media-3405-company.p‌​ng',function(file){document.getElementById("downloaded").src = file;});` and I get this src when I inspect it on remote safari web inspector `<img id="downloaded" src="file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/6E7CC93B-2D8B-401A-BD93-3981FF95F34B/Documents/-a%CC%82%E2%82%AC%C5%92a%CC%82%E2%82%AC%E2%80%B9media-3405-company.pa%CC%82%E2%82%AC%C5%92a%CC%82%E2%82%AC%E2%80%B9ng"/>` . At this point, you should also try to debug your app on safari

Comment: Note that the `-‌​media-3405-company.p‌​ng` is getting renamed to `-‌​a%CC%82%E2%82%AC%C5%‌​92a%CC%82%E2%82%AC%E‌​2%80%B9media-3405-co‌​mpany.pa%CC%82%E2%82‌​%AC%C5%92a%CC%82%E2%‌​82%AC%E2%80%B9ng`, I get that url on `fileEntry.toURL()`.

Comment: Also, do you have a Content-Security-Policy meta tag in your index.html? It might be preventing the images to load.

Comment: I've spent some time enabling Safari debugging, and can now confirm that I get an error "Failed to load resource: The operation couldn’t be completed. Operation not permitted" when i try to load the `file:///`-url. I've tried including the following Content Security Policy in my index.html-file: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * filesystem filesystem: 'unsafe-inline' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; connect-src *;">` with the same results. What did you add?

Comment: I used the default one, also tried with yours now and it's still working

Comment: @feupeu I've uploaded my project to github, it's a new cordova project where I just put your code with minor changes

Comment: @jcesarmobile Hi jcesar, could you post the github prokect link please

Comment: Ah, sorry, failed to paste the url https://github.com/jcesarmobile/downloadFileTest

Comment: I've downloaded the project you've provided, and it works for me too. As far as I can see, we're doing the same thing. However, I *still* get the message `Failed to load resource: The operation couldn’t be completed. Operation not permitted` whenever I try to access files on the disk. I've also tried modifying the src manually through Safari debug tool, resulting in the message `Failed to load resource: {url} The requested URL was not found on this server`. This would indicate that I do not have permissions to load the files. This is the same with mine, yours or no Content-Security-Policy

Comment: Also: Im using [ember-cordova](http://embercordova.com/), however, as far as I know, this only generates a normal Cordova project for you. Currently, I'm going through the project you provided, seeing if I can spot any differences

Comment: @feupeu can you try to open the file on inAppBrowser plugin? install the plugin first and the try with `window.open(file,'_blank');`, just to check that the file is there, inAppBrowser shouldn't have any permission problem to open it.

Comment: The inAppBrowser plugin is displaying the images correctly

Comment: I have updated my sample with the plugins and platform saved, check it and let me know if you are using different cordova-ios or plugins versions https://github.com/jcesarmobile/downloadFileTest/blob/master/config.xml#L26-L28

Comment: Using the same versions as you for the different plugins and ios engine seems to have *fixed the issue*. The only difference in versions is that I'm using `<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.2" />`. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: iOS doesn't really use the whitelist plugin, so no problem about that. Can you let me know which version were you using so I can figure out what was failing in your app?